# Convert date time to below format SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to obtain date in this format:
'05-31-2014 01:20:25 AM'

I used below code:
[Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/18095), but output date strangely changed to a different date: `30-26-2011 01:30:38 AM`

```
select format(CAST('2011-11-26 01:30:38.000' AS datetime), 'mm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```

Sql Fiddle here

Comment: Use `convert()`, explicitly choosing the format that you want.  Don't depend on system defaults.

Comment: First priority - Use Convert(). If you want to use same query change `mm` to `MM`. `select format(CAST('2011-11-26 01:30:38.000' AS datetime), 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `FORMAT()` function, `mm` is minutes, `MM` is month, so change to:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('2011-11-26 01:30:38.000' AS DATETIME), 'MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
```

If there's already an appropriate format available via `CONVERT()`, that is preferable as it performs better than the `FORMAT()` function.